# Is it possible to execute a BACKUP statement using a parameterised query?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

Iam using above sql command. But the parameters are not adding. I have 2 textboxes to specify location and name. but its not passing to the query. Any solution?

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS);
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand("BACKUP DATABASE BillingSoftware TO DISK = '@Loc:\\@Name.BAK'",con);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Loc", textBox_BackupDatabaseLocation.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", textBox_BackupDatabaseName.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: You are trying to use parameters as if they were string substitution variables. They aren't. *Assuming* that `BACKUP DATABASE` accepts parameters, just pass the full path as a single parameter, ie `TO DISK =@fullPath`

Comment: Why dont' you just pass the full path as a single parameter? You can construct a correct value with `Path.Combine()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing two separate parameters and trying to concatenate them in the SQL script, just pass the complete path as a single parameter. You can create a valid path from a folder and filename with [System.IO.Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var folder=textBox_BackupDatabaseLocation.Text;
var filename = textBox_BackupDatabaseName.Text;
var fullPath=Path.Combine(folder,filename);

//...
var cmd= new SqlCommand("BACKUP DATABASE BillingSoftware TO DISK = @fullPath",con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fullPath", fullPath);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

`Path.Combine` generates a correct file path even if there are eg trailing or missing slashes in the folder name, which would make string concatenation break.

Another option is to *avoid* SQL statements and use the [SQL Server Management Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh248032.aspx) library. In the end, SMO generates SQL commands but it exposes all functionality in an API that *should* make finding and specifying additional options very easy.

I say *should* because the documentation isn't up to SQL Server standards. The [class reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.backup.aspx) is there but the examples ... Check [Backing Up and Restoring Databases and Transaction Logs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162133.aspx). Perhaps there is a better SO Documentation page for this.

Anyway, the example code can be distilled to this:

```
//Local server
var srv = new Server();  
var db = srv.Databases["AdventureWorks2012"];    
var bk = new Backup
         {
             Action = BackupActionType.Database,
             BackupSetDescription = "Full backup of Adventureworks2012",
             BackupSetName = "AdventureWorks2012 Backup",
             Database = "AdventureWorks2012",
             Checksum = true
         };

var bdi = new BackupDeviceItem(fullDestinationPath,DeviceType.File);  
bk.Devices.Add(bdi);  
bk.SqlBackup(srv);
```

The advantage is that you can target multiple databases eg in a loop, get progress notifications etc.

**UPDATE**

The [Path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) class contains methods that can be used to validate paths, eg [Path.IsPathRooted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.ispathrooted(v=vs.110).aspx) can be used to check whether the path is a full path. Other `System.IO` classes can be used for validation, eg [Directory.Exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists(v=vs.110).aspx) check if a folder exists.

Comment: Good Answer.. Thank you.

Comment: i should input location like D:\.. I dont want the user to input ":\". How to do that.

Comment: @Abhijith you mean how to validate the paths? I added an update. You can use `Path.IsPathRooted` to check if the path is an absolute one, and/or `Directory.Exists` to check if the folder actually exists

Comment: most of people here will criticize you. Don't care for them @PanagiotisKanavos

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to concatenate `disk location` and database `backup filename` seperately, you should add `+` for concatenation of both to get absolute path of the bak file.

Try using following query:

```
SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand("BACKUP DATABASE BillingSoftware TO DISK = @Loc + ':\\' + @Name + '.BAK'",con);
```

Comment: I doubt if this will work. The parameters might be filled in but the + will not be accepted by sql server

Comment: Any Solution then?

Answer (score 0):

Since after reading your comments, you need to pass these two parameters separately. You need to create variable at each line and then use for concatenation since t-sql does not allow concatenation of variables directly. I got a workaround for you:

```
declare @drive varchar(max);declare @path varchar(max);declare @fullpath varchar(max);set @drive = @Loc + ':\\';set @path = @Name + '.bak' ;set @fullpath = @drive + @path;BACKUP DATABASE BillingSoftware TO DISK = @fullpath
```

It looks some extra, but will fulfill your need. Thank me later!

To save yourself from SQL injection, better concatenate filename and path at `c#` side:

```
string dbBackupName = "some name here.bak";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("BACKUP DATABASE BillingSoftware TO DISK = @dbFullName", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dbFullName", textBox_BackupDatabaseLocation.Text + "\\" + dbBackupName);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: String concatenation is the *problem*, not the solution. Parameterized queries are used to *avoid* concatenation and SQL injection

Comment: there will no SQL injection in this case, since we are giving parameters.

Comment: No you aren't. You are *concatenating strings* in the script itself. If you could write `TO DISK = @somepath` why not pass the full path as a parameter?

Comment: because it's the need of person who ask the question. Read his comments.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos he did not mention if he don't want SQL injection

Comment: Misconceptions aren't needs. It's very easy to just pass a correct parameter value

Comment: Is it prone to SQL Injection? Its the main file iam backing up!

Comment: @Abhijith just create the full path with `Path.Combine` and pass it as a single parameter

Comment: @Abhijith I will advice you to use only one parameter, since you are concatenating it. That's dangerous. Better concatenate from `C#` and then pass the parameter as single param in query.

Comment: @Umer.. I always use parameterized queries. So i checked with database backup also.

Comment: @Abhijith i edited my answer. Check to get rid of SQL injection!

Comment: @Umar you are using `DISK = '@dbFullName'`. That's a string literal, not a parameter placeholder. The statement will fail because the path is invalid. You should use `DISK = @dbFullName`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i ran that under management studio. It works fine. Hope it will work in C# side too :)

Comment: You run a different query -`BACKUP DATABASE BillingSoftware TO DISK = @fullpath`. While your C# code uses `BACKUP DATABASE BillingSoftware TO DISK = '@dbFullName'` and *doesn't* set the parameter at all. It still sets `@Loc` at `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Loc",`. It's as if you tried to execute `BACKUP DATABASE BillingSoftware TO DISK = '@fullpath'` in SSMS

Comment: Your C# code will run but it will store the backup in a file named `@dbFullName` in SQL Server's default backup directory

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I edited my answer, sorry I just copy pasted from my machine and ssms together :)