# SQL parametrized query for restoring backup file

Tags: c#, sql, sonarqube, sql-injection, prepared-statement

I want to refactor the following sql query using parametrized query. Is it possible?

```
 string cmd= $@" IF EXISTS(select * from sys.databases where name='{ dbname}')
                                    ALTER DATABASE[{ dbname}] 
                                    SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;

                                    RESTORE DATABASE[{ dbname}]  
                                    FROM DISK = '{backupFile}'
                                    WITH REPLACE,
                                    MOVE '{mdfFileName}' TO '{sqlDataFolderPath}{dbname}.MDF',   
                                    MOVE '{logFileName}' TO '{sqlDataFolderPath}{dbname}.LDF';

                                    ALTER DATABASE[{ dbname}] 
                                    SET ONLINE ";

            SqlCommand cmd= con.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = sqlCommand;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

As a first step I  used a parametrized query to retrive the information regarding mdf and ldf via RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = @backupFilePath. And the next step should be the restore operation. Currently is working only with the above approach but I would like to refactor it in order to solve the security hotspot reported by sonar (sql injection) .

**UPDATE:**

I've tried to use the same approach as for BACKUP but without success, no error is thrown but the mdf, ldf files are not moved.

```
string sqlDynamicQuery = "DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = (" +
                                         "SELECT 'ALTER DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(name) + " +
                                         "' SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;'" +
                                         "+ ' RESTORE DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(name) + " +
                                         "' FROM DISK = @backupfilepath WITH REPLACE, " +
                                         "MOVE @mdfFileName TO @mdfFilePath, " +
                                         "MOVE @logFileName TO @ldfFilePath ' " +
                                         "+ ' ALTER DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(name) +" +
                                         "'SET ONLINE ' from sys.databases where name= @database); "+
                                         "EXEC sp_executesql "+
                                         "@sql, " +
                                         "N'@backupfilepath nvarchar(128), @mdfFileName nvarchar(128),  @mdfFilePath  nvarchar(128), @logFileName nvarchar(128),  @ldfFilePath  nvarchar(128)', "+
                                         "@backupfilepath = @backupfilepath, "+
                                         "@mdfFileName = @mdfFileName, "+
                                         "@mdfFilePath = @mdfFilePath, "+
                                         "@logFileName = @logFileName, "+
                                         "@ldfFilePath = @ldfFilePath; ";

                using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlDynamicQuery, _sqlConnection))
                {
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@database", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128).Value = databaseName;
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@backupfilepath", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128).Value = backupFile;
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@mdfFileName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128).Value = model.MdfFileName;
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@mdfFilePath", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128).Value = Path.Combine(_sqlDataFolderPath, databaseName + ".MDF");
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@logFileName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128).Value = model.LogFileName;
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ldfFilePath", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128).Value = Path.Combine(_sqlDataFolderPath, databaseName + ".LDF");

                    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
```

I have also tried in ssms

```
DECLARE @database nvarchar(128)
DECLARE @backupfilepath nvarchar(128)
DECLARE @mdfFilePath nvarchar(128)
DECLARE @ldfFilePath nvarchar(128)
DECLARE @mdfFileName nvarchar(128)
DECLARE @logFileName nvarchar(128)

SET @database = 'v1'
set @backupfilepath = 'C:\\Data\\MyDocs\\DatabaseBak\\v1.bak'
SET @mdfFileName = 'p1'
SET @logFileName = 'p1_log'
SET @mdfFilePath = 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\\MSSQL\\DATA\\v1.MDF'
SET @ldfFilePath = 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\\MSSQL\\DATA\\v1.LDF'



DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = (SELECT 'ALTER DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ' SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;' +  ' RESTORE DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ' FROM DISK = @backupfilepath WITH REPLACE, MOVE @mdfFileName TO @mdfFilePath, MOVE @logFileName TO @ldfFilePath '+ ' ALTER DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(name) + 'SET ONLINE  ' from sys.databases where name= @database);
print @sql
EXEC sp_executesql
    @sql,
    N'@backupfilepath nvarchar(128), @mdfFileName nvarchar(128),  @mdfFilePath  nvarchar(128), @logFileName nvarchar(128),  @ldfFilePath  nvarchar(128)',
    @backupfilepath = @backupfilepath,
    @mdfFileName = @mdfFileName,
    @mdfFilePath = @mdfFilePath,
    @logFileName = @logFileName,
    @ldfFilePath = @ldfFilePath;
```

**UPDATE:**

It works now on SSMS:

```
DECLARE @database nvarchar(128)
DECLARE @backupfilepath nvarchar(128)
DECLARE @mdfFilePath nvarchar(128)
DECLARE @ldfFilePath nvarchar(128)
DECLARE @mdfFileName nvarchar(128)
DECLARE @logFileName nvarchar(128)

SET @database = 'v1'
set @backupfilepath = 'C:\\Data\\MyDocs\\DatabaseBak\\v1.bak'
SET @mdfFileName = 'p1'
SET @logFileName = 'p1_log'
SET @mdfFilePath = 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\\MSSQL\\DATA\\v1.MDF'
SET @ldfFilePath = 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\\MSSQL\\DATA\\v1.LDF'


DECLARE @SQLString nvarchar(max) ='IF EXISTS(select * from sys.databases where name='+'''' + @database +''''+')'+
   'ALTER DATABASE [' + @database + '] ' +
   'SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE ' +
   'RESTORE DATABASE ['+@database +
   '] FROM  DISK ='+ '''' + @backupfilepath +''''+
   ' WITH  REPLACE,  '+
   'MOVE '+''''+@mdfFileName+''''+ ' TO '+ '''' + @mdfFilePath +''''+',  '+
   'MOVE '+''''+@logFileName+''''+ ' TO '+ '''' + @ldfFilePath +''''+';  '+
   'ALTER DATABASE [' + @database + '] ' +
   'SET ONLINE '
print @SQLString


EXEC sp_executesql
    @SQLString,
    N'@database nvarchar(128), @backupfilepath nvarchar(128), @mdfFileName nvarchar(128),  @mdfFilePath  nvarchar(128), @logFileName nvarchar(128),  @ldfFilePath  nvarchar(128)',
    @database = @database,
    @backupfilepath = @backupfilepath,
    @mdfFileName = @mdfFileName,
    @mdfFilePath = @mdfFilePath,
    @logFileName = @logFileName,
    @ldfFilePath = @ldfFilePath;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Parametrized query for database backup is reported as sql injection by sonarqube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65572116/sql-parametrized-query-for-database-backup-is-reported-as-sql-injection-by-sonar)

Comment: SQL Parametrized query for database backup is reported as sql injection by sonarqube – Charlieface - this thread solves the backup sql query. Now I would like to load a .bak file using a parametrized query. As a first step I  used a parametrized query to retrive the information regarding mdf and ldf via RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = @backupFilePath. And the next step should be the restore step. Currently is working only with the above approach but I would like to refactor it .

Comment: Use the same method I showed in that thread for `RESTORE`. Only the DB name cannot be parameterized directly, don't forget to use `QUOTENAME`

Comment: I think the following statements  cannot be done inside a parametrized query, I have tried in ssms but got only errors.                                                                                                                   ALTER DATABASE[{ dbname}] ....etc

Comment: That is what I said about `BACKUP`, you cannot parameterize the DB. Follow the method I wrote, not what you have. I.e. get the DB name from `sys.databases`, qoute it and add it to the dynamic statement.

Comment: I have updated the dynamic query using the same approach as BACKUP but it seems that the query returns null due to the fact that the .mdf and .ldf files are not moved properly . If I use the original query (without parameters), everything goes well , and I cannot figure it out what I'm doing wrong. I have updated the description with the last query.

Comment: If `@sql` is null then you have the database name wrong. Or is it an actual error message? You have double backslash in the filenames. Docs are somewhat unclear but say: `MOVE 'logical_file_name_in_backup' TO 'operating_system_file_name'` which indicates you may not be able to parameterize those. I have seen examples online with variables for filenames though.